# Read all selected item from dropdown

Tags: html, internet-explorer, select, vbscript

First post, just learning HTML:

I am writting a VBS script and using "IE" as a GUI. I have created a multi "Select" dropdown box and I can read the first selected option but dont know how to read the rest of the selected items. And they are not always sequentual, such as the selected items may by the 3rd, 6th, and ninth option. Below is the Select box setup and below that are the commands to read the first option to get the index and value.

```
"<form action='form_action.asp'> "&_
"<select  size='10' id='cars' name='cars' multiple>"&_
"<option value='volvo1234'>Volvo12345</option>"&_
"<option value='saab'>Saab</option>"&_
"<option value='opel'>Opel</option>"&_
"<option value='audi'>Audi</option>"&_
"<option value='ford'>Ford</option>"&_
"<option value='chevy'>Chevy</option>"&_
"<option value='olds'>Olds</option>"&_
"<option value='pontiac'>Pontiac</option>"&_
"</select>"&_
"<button name=SELECT AccessKey=O "&_
         "Onclick=document.all(""ButtonHandler"").value=""SELECT"";" & _
          "><b>SELECT</button></b>" & _
"</form>"&_
 ================================

Select Case g_objIE.Document.All("ButtonHandler").Value
Case "SELECT"
g_objIE.Document.All("ButtonHandler").Value = ""
call read_sel
=======================

function read_sel()
index = g_objIE.document.getElementById("cars").selectedIndex
value= g_objIE.document.getElementById("cars").value

msgbox "value=" & value & " index=" & index    

end function
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Note:  Just found the post that talks about having to add the brackets after "name="cars[]" .will contiune to make use of that.. Might solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop like this:

```
For Each opt In g_objIE.document.getElementById("cars").options
  If opt.selected Then MsgBox opt.text
Next
```

Comment: I guess I was trying to make it too complicated. That works great. Thanks so much

Comment: The "opt.text" was not something I have seen before but works like a charm